# Python using Selenium select year in Datetimepicker

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I would like the datetimepicker to select the start year '2021', but the code gives me year 2022, I use:

```
driver.get('http://www.sse.com.cn/disclosure/bond/announcement/company/')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
datefield_st = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
datefield_st.click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[12]/div[3]/table/thead/tr[1]/th[2]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datetimepicker-years']//table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format("2021")))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='datetimepicker-months']//table/tbody/tr/td/span[text()='{}']".format("十二月")))).click()
day=15
```

But still not selecting year 2021, any help will be appreciated! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
date_input = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "start_date")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '2021-01-01';", date_input)
date_input.click()
```

To make that date anything you want you can just set it's value.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help! May I ask how driver.execute_script work?

Comment: Basically it runs javascript to set the elements value.

Comment: thanks! may I ask how I can find the tutorial or materials about that function?